# MySQL - How can I insert multiple rows using select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
insert into unique_products values (product_id, serial_numnber, pronexo_code, entry_time, exit_time, guarantee_long, expanded_guarantee_long)
select product_id, serial_number, pronexo_code, start_guarantee_date, start_guarantee_date, guarantee_long, expanded_guarantee_long
from table_24
```

It throws this error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select product_id, serial_number, pronexo_code, start_guarantee_date, start_guar' at line 2

Does anybody know what's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `VALUES` key word from your Query.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO unique_products (product_id, serial_numnber, pronexo_code, entry_time, exit_time, guarantee_long, expanded_guarantee_long)
SELECT product_id, serial_number, pronexo_code, start_guarantee_date, start_guarantee_date, guarantee_long, expanded_guarantee_long
FROM table_24;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
  insert into unique_products (product_id, serial_numnber, 
  pronexo_code, entry_time, exit_time, guarantee_long, 
  expanded_guarantee_long)
  select product_id, serial_number, pronexo_code, start_guarantee_date, 
  start_guarantee_date, guarantee_long, expanded_guarantee_long
  from table_24
```

Answer (score 1):

Take care at the SQL syntax and at the field name typing:

`VALUE` keyword is incorrect here, and watch `serial_numnber` or `serial_number` correct spelling for your field name:

```
insert into unique_products (product_id, SERIAL_NUMBER, pronexo_code, entry_time, exit_time, guarantee_long, expanded_guarantee_long)
select product_id, SERIAL_NUMBER, pronexo_code, start_guarantee_date, start_guarantee_date, guarantee_long, expanded_guarantee_long
from table_24
```

Details on correct *INSERT-INTO-SELECT* syntax [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp).